# PHP autoload oddity

Tags: php, autoload

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    echo("Attempting autoload ");
    if (substr($class_name, -6) == "Mapper") {
        $file = 'mappers/'.$class_name.'.php';
        echo "Will autoload $file ";
        include_once($file);
    }
}
__autoload("UserMapper");
$user = new UserMapper($adapter);

die("done");
```

*Result:*
**Attempting autoload Will autoload mappers/UserMapper.php done**

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    echo("Attempting autoload ");
    if (substr($class_name, -6) == "Mapper") {
        $file = 'mappers/'.$class_name.'.php';
        echo "Will autoload $file ";
        include_once($file);
    }
}
//__autoload("UserMapper");
$user = new UserMapper($adapter);

die("done");
```

(I just commented out the manual call to __autoload()...)

*Result:*
**Fatal error: Class 'UserMapper' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\proj\29letters\login.php on line 13**

Any ideas?
And yes, I'm running PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Are you running in CLI interactive mode?

Comment: All I can think of is that there may be some other __autoload function declared somewhere else, but I thought that should generate some kind of error to inform you of the fact that you're trying to redeclare __autoload.  There's nothing in the code to explain why it wouldn't output anything at all, it should at the very least output "attempting autoload".

Comment: phpinfo says: "Server API: Apache 2.0 Handle". It's not CLI as far as I know. I also don't think there is an autoload function somewhere else, since I was able to define it and call it manually, plus it's mostly my code. This is very weird but I don't have much energy to investigate, spl_autoload_register worked well for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why your example isn't working, as it should be as per the manual.

Have you tried using [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) to register the autoloader function?

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by putting it in the root file of the applicaion, but I'll give spl_autoload_register a try.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be using __autoload anyways (as only one can be defined). Use spl_autoload_register instead. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a proper `include_path`? You're using a relative path to include the class's file. Try an absolute path instead.

```
$dir  = __DIR__ . '/../path/to/mappers';
$file = $dir . '/' . $class_name . '.php';
require $file;
```

or

```
// do this outside of __autoload
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ . '/../path/to/mappers';

// inside __autoload
$file = $class_name . '.php';
require $file;
```

Comment: I'm using a path relative to the root file. The same path works well for include() and require(). Does __autload() read the path in a different way?

Comment: `__DIR__` represents the path of the file it is defined in.

Comment: I guess __autoload will use the path the function is defined in. Not sure though.

Comment: It's not defined in any function. The root file is admin.php which includes login.php. Both files are in the same directory, and the path is relative to that directory.

Comment: I mean the __autoload function.